# increase weight precision in magento backend

Tags: php, magento

Hello StackOverflow world,

I have one problem in magento weight attribute.

Magento uses 4 decimal places for weight attribute which I wish to use it up-to 6 decimal places for weight calculation in shipping rates in the back-end only.

Please let me now how to increase the decimal precision for weight in magento CE 1.9.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason that the attribute is 4 decimal places is because the table is set as such. All decimal attributes are stored in the table `catalog_category_entity_decimal` and if you look at the fields you will see that the value has the type "decimal(12,4)".

What you can do is update this table to use `decimal(12,6)` but then this will have an effect on all decimal attributes stored in Magento.

Comment: thanks for reply but it didn't work. I still have weight up-to 4 precision.

Answer (score 1):

To change the decimal precision of attributes that have a backend_type set to decimal,

You have to change the type of value in this table :

```
catalog_product_entity_decimal
```

If you have not change yet, you should see :

```
decimal(12,4)
```